# SQL - Select all Rows, from specific columns, whilst counting individual things

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to work this out in SQLite3, and been failing for hours now!

Imagine I have this table (named products), for example purposes:

```
Company | Product | Price (£)
--------|---------|----------
Apple   | iPhone  |   349
Samsung | Galaxy  |   300
Sony    | PS4     |   229
Sony    | Xperia  |   249
```

What query would I use, to show how many products there are by each company? Presenting similar results to the following:

```
Company |   ???
--------|---------
Apple   | 1 
Samsung | 1 
Sony    | 2
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as it's stressing me out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Group by the `company` and then use the aggregate function `count()`. Aggregate functions apply to each group if there are groups.

```
select company, count(*)
from your_table
group by company
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Highly appreciated - never thought of grouping them for some reason!